# Exclude files from Cypress.io Coverage Report

Tags: code-coverage, cypress

Hi Im using cypress coverage report but I have a class which houses all touch device specific functionality and as I'm running the tests on my Mac, they never run. Is there any way to exclude this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to check [cypress coverage readme](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#exclude-files-and-folders):

...

```
"nyc": {
   "include": [...],
   "exclude": [...]
}
```

...

Comment: You need to add "excludeAfterRemap": true just like Srkigres said.

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't work:

```
"nyc": {
   "exclude": [...]
}
```

Then add one more property like this:

```
"nyc": {
   "exclude": [...],
   "excludeAfterRemap": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On cypress version 10, what worked for me is to create a .nycrc.json file which contains

```
{
  "exclude": [...],
}
```